# Time evolution operator of the free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

I never came across an example of what the explicit form of a time evolution operator looks like. So when $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ does the time evolution operator look like
$$
U(t,t_0)=\exp\Big(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^t H_s dt\Big)=\exp\Big(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{p^2}{2m}(t-t_0)\Big)
$$
that? And if yes, what does $p$ mean? Is it the operator $\hat{p}$ or the actual momentum of the particle once it's measured?

Comment: It is the operator representing the momentum observable.

Comment: If the Hamiltonian $H$ is time-independent, the time-evolution operator is always $e^{-iH(t-t_0)}$.

Comment: and if the hamiltonian is time-independent, is then also the schroedinger hamiltonian always equal to the heisenberg hamiltonian ?

Comment: @petermafai Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a time-independent Hamiltonian $H$, one has that
$$U(t,t_0):= e^{-iH(t-t_0)/\hbar}$$
If the spectrum of $H$ is discrete and $\{|\phi_n\rangle\}$ is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $H$ with eigenvalues $\{E_n\}$, then this operator can be written
$$U(t,t_0) = \sum_n e^{-i E_n(t-t_0)/\hbar} |\phi_n\rangle\langle\phi_n|$$

---

In the somewhat more complicated case that the spectrum of $H$ is purely continuous with *generalized* "orthnormal" eigenvectors $\{|\varphi(\lambda)\rangle\}$ and generalized eigenvalues $\{E(\lambda)\}$, then we have

$$U(t,t_0) = \int \mathrm d\lambda \ e^{-i E(\lambda)(t-t_0)/\hbar} |\varphi(\lambda)\rangle\langle\varphi(\lambda)|$$
This is what we have in the case of a free particle on a line, where the Hamiltonian is given by $\hat p^2/2m$ and a convenient generalized eigenbasis is given by the momentum basis $|p\rangle= \int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} e^{-ipx/\hbar}|x\rangle$:

$$U(t,t_0) = e^{-i\hat p^2(t-t_0)/2m\hbar} = \int \mathrm dp \ e^{-ip^2(t-t_0)/2m\hbar} |p\rangle\langle p|$$